# Saving event in Fullcalendar using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar and I would like to save events when I click on the calendar.

This is what I have so far, which is working with the submitted elements from the form but not from the calendar, for example I cannot get the start date.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
...
select: function(start, end, allDay, event, resourceId) { 
$('#add_appt').modal(); //openthemodal

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#EventAdd').submit(function(e) {
        SubmitAppointment();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

function SubmitAppointment(){
    hideshow('loading',1);
    error(0);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.events.add.php",

// If I try this, I get all the elements of the form but no value for start I think it's my syntax that is wrong
        data: $('#EventAdd').serialize(),start: start, 

// If I try this, I get the start date but I don't know how to include the vales in EventAdd
        data: 'start='+ start,

        dataType: "json",

        success: function(msg){
            if(parseInt(msg.status)==1){
                $('#add_appt').modal('hide');
                //window.location=msg.txt;
            }else if(parseInt(msg.status)==0){
                error(1,msg.txt);
            }
        hideshow('loading',0);
        }
    });
}
```

Can someone help me with the syntax ? Because I think that's where the problem really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have to pass the `data` parameter of your ajax call as follows if you want to send all your `<form>` values and `start` value:

`data: $('#EventAdd').serialize() + "&start=" + start`

Comment: Yes this is the correct way of doing it ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer to my own question :

I use this :

```
data: 'start='+ start+$('#EventAdd').serialize(),
```

instead of this

```
data: $('#EventAdd').serialize(),start: start,
```